# ExpressJs Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, cors

I have created RESTful API in express and calling API from nextjs both hosted in heroku.

For GET requests things work perfectly. I can fetch data from API, but for POST request I was getting following error

[image]

For the past 2 days, I can't solve this problem.

In API I have enabled cors and tried many methods to enable cors.

It's working for GET request but not for POST request

**server.js**

```
import cors from "cors";
...

//Try 1
const whitelist = ["https://pixkiryaclient1.herokuapp.com"];

const corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
  let corsOptions;

  const isDomainAllowed = whitelist.indexOf(req.header("Origin")) !== -1;
  if (isDomainAllowed) {
    // Enable CORS for this request
    corsOptions = { origin: true };
  } else {
    // Disable CORS for this request
    corsOptions = { origin: false };
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions);
};
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));


//Try 2
// app.use(
//   cors({
//     origin: "https://pixkiryaclient1.herokuapp.com",
//     methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
//     preflightContinue: false,
//     optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
//   })
// );


// Try 3
// app.use(function (req, res, next) {
//   res.setHeader(
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
//     "https://pixkiryaclient1.herokuapp.com"
//   );
//   // res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
//   // res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
//   // res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
//   next();
// });


//Try 4
// const whitelist = ["https://pixkiryaclient1.herokuapp.com"];

// const corsOptions = {
//   //@ts-ignore
//   origin: function (origin, callback) {
//     if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
//       callback(null, true);
//     } else {
//       callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
//     }
//   },

//   credentials: true,
// };

// app.use(cors(corsOptions));



//Try 5

// const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
//   origin: "https://pixkiryaclient1.herokuapp.com",
//   optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
//   methods: "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE",
// };

// app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

None of the above trys working for POST requests.

**In nextJS I am calling API as:**

```
 const res = await post(
   'https://pixkiryaapi.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/login',
   {
     body: { email, password },
   }
 );
```

**post.js**

```
const axiosIntance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://pixkiryaapi.herokuapp.com/api/v1',
  responseType: 'json',
});


export function post(
  url,
  { params = {}, body = {}} = {}
) {
  return axiosIntance({
    url,
    params,
    data: body,
    method: 'POST',
  }).then((response) => response.data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are trying to make a call to the herokuapp.com domain from localhost, its getting blocked by CORS.

Try using Next.js rewrites to proxy your backend call thru localhost.

Reference: [Next.js Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: 'https://pixkiryaapi.herokuapp.com/api/:path*' // Proxy to Backend
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can try running your backend service locally too and add condition in your code to call localhost if running locally.

Comment: i have hosted both nextjs app and express api in heroku

Comment: I got confused with the localhost white list. Have you tried to update your origin policies in `next.config.js`? Follow this - https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-enable-cors#enabling-cors-in-a-next.js-app

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. I switched the protocol (http => https) and the problem was solved. From what I've read, CORS errors are most commonly caused by incorrect protocols and protection plugins, like Enhanced Browser Protection for firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed